# How can I rename long file names?

Tags: 18.04

I was told I can rename and shorten file names that have more than 255 characters (including file pathway entries) using Ubuntu. How can I do this?

Comment: Are you currently running Ubuntu?

Comment: No offense but I would not be on this forum if i was not using Ubuntu. Yes I use Ubuntu 18.04.2

Comment: The wording in your question lent itself to "I have a problem with Windows..."

Comment: i said absolutely nothing about windows

Comment: I didn't intend to offend - there are a lot of questions on this site related to Windows - people starting to use Ubuntu, or having problems with dual-boot, or using WSL.

Answer (score 2):

Most of this will be done using a terminal window, and typed commands, often referred to as CLI, for command line interface.

---

The first way that you might try to shorten your fully defined path and filename, is to move the files in question to a shorter path.

Using a terminal window, this is done with the `mv` command as outlined below.

1st, open a terminal window (press ctrl+alt+t)

Let's assume that the full pathname to a file is

`/This/Is/The/First/Part/Of/A/Long/Path/And/Here/Is/My/file.name`

where the first part log the long pathname is not of interest.  You must first create a destination directory to store the files of interest.  First let's make sure that you are in your home directory

`cd ~`

Now lets create a directory to store the renamed files:

`mkdir ./Shortpath`

Now we could move just the one file to the new `Shortpath` directory:

`mv /This/Is/The/First/Part/Of/A/Long/Path/And/Here/Is/My/file.name ./Shortpath/`

Now the file `file.name` is in the `Shortpath` directory in your home directory.  The full pathname to the file is `/home/<username>/Shortpath/file.name` where `<username>` is your user name.

That's fine for a single file, and a little modification makes it move entire subdirectories:

`mv /This/Is/The/First/Part/Of/A/Long/Path/And/Here ./Shortpath/`

moves the directory named `Here` from the long path, to the `Shortpath` directory, so the full name for the file would now be `/home/<username>/Shortpath/Here/Is/My/file.name`

So, by using `mv` (see `man mv`) you can move files, or directory structures, from the end of long paths to shorter paths.

---

This is all well and fine if you want to permanently move the files from a long and unwieldy path, to a short path permanently.  Sometimes you just want to do it for a little while, and for that I'm going to use `mount` (see `man mount`) to create a short path to the files, that will go away the next time you reboot.

Again lets assume that the long path is

`/This/Is/The/First/Part/Of/A/Long/Path/And/Here/Is/My/file.name`

and the part you are interested in begins at the `Here`

Using `mount` with the `--bind` option, we can add a new directory structure to your linux system, so that the path tot he file is much shorter.

First, make sure that a directory we will use as a *mountpoint* exists:

`ls -ld /mnt`

should return something like

`drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Apr 16 11:59 /mnt`

if it does not, the command `sudo mkdir /mnt` will create the directory.  You need to use `sudo` for this, as regular users can't create directories at the root level.

Now we can connect the directory structure of the long path, starting at `Here` to your file system with the command

You *might* try using

`sudo mount --bind /This/Is/The/First/Part/Of/A/Long/Path/And/Here /mnt`

Now *a path* to your file is `/mnt/Is/My/file.name`

Please note that the file *has not been moved* - there a are now two fully valid paths to the file:

`/mnt/Is/My/file.name` and `/This/Is/The/First/Part/Of/A/Long/Path/And/Here/Is/My/file.name` point to exactly the same place on the disk.

When you are done manipulating files, and you don't need the path mounted anymore, you can execute the command

`sudo umount /mnt`

which will disconnect the path, or you can reboot.  Either way, the mount will be gone.

---

Some useful information:

In a terminal window, information about commands can be found in the Manuals which are  installed in Linux:

`man mv` show the manual pages for `mv`

Other commands used here were `ls`, `mkdir`, `mount`, `umount`, `sudo`.  All of these also have pages in the manuals.

Comment: I have no idea what you are trying to say, I am relatively new to this. could you explain how step by step in greater detail? @Charles Green

Comment: @MikePeterson Sure - but I think I should ask are you just trying to find the files, access the files, or move them to a shorter directory path?

Comment: I want to move them to a shorter directory path.

Comment: @MikePeterson OK, I'll expand the answer, and provide details for two methods.